# Get S3 object size with Ansible

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

There's a backup script that dumps some databases and uploads the backups to S3.

I'm writing an Ansible playbook to check the S3 backup sizes independently, from some other host. It would alert me if size is less than X GiB as that would indicate a failed backup. Nothing unknown so far, but...

I don't seem to be able get the requested object size from S3 bucket with `aws_s3` module. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is an S3 module available that allows running `ls` commands over S3 Buckets. What you could do is run an `aws s3api` command, using the `command` module.

```
---
- name: Get S3 object size
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - ./secret.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Get the `list-object` result for the `object`
      command: >
        aws s3api list-objects
          --bucket {{ bucket }}
          --prefix {{ object }}
      register: output

    - name: Parse the `list-object` output
      set_fact:
        object_size: '{{ output.stdout | from_json | json_query("Contents[0].Size") }}'
```

I hope it helps

Comment: was hoping for "native" solution without outside dependency, but maybe there isn't one yet.

Comment: I couldn't find one. Most modules have a `aws_module_facts` version that lets you gather information about your resources, but there doesn't seem to be one for S3. Creating one could be a good thing for the community, though. I'll take a crack at it as soon as I got the time.